# Google Cloud Repository

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to access the Google Cloud Repository through git. I am doing this from a CentOS 6 Google Compute Engine. I have some firewall ports configured though CSF, though as far as I can tell the ports that need to be open are open:

```
TCP_IN = "20,21,22,23,25,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,993,995,25565"
TCP_OUT = "20,21,22,23,25,53,80,110,113,443,587,993,995,25565"
```

My Google firewall ports that are open:

```
tcp:27015,27016,8766; udp:27015,27016,8766
tcp:80
tcp:443
icmp
tcp:3389
tcp:22
tcp:8000
tcp:9418; udp:9418
tcp:25565
tcp:1000; udp:1000
tcp:4000
tcp:32400
tcp:20-22,10000-10100
tcp:8888
tcp:3784; udp:3784
tcp: 3389
tcp:3389,1,2,5000-6000; udp:3389,1,2,5000-6000
```

A lot of these are for other services I run on the VM. However, when I run

```
git clone https://source.developers.google.com/p/<project-ID-here>/
```

I get this error:

```
fatal: https://source.developers.google.com/p/<project-ID-here>//info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

I have tried it with and without the slash at the end of `<project-ID-here>`, in case the double slashes was breaking something, but I get the same result. I think I've opened up the network enough to let git through, but for some reason it just doesn't go through.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate using the `gcloud auth login` command. See [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/cloud-repositories-local-repository#add_the_repository_as_a_remote) on that topic.

As far as I know, [it is not possible to authenticate using a service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073764/using-google-cloud-platform-repositories-with-service-account) or some other automated way.