# Using Google Cloud Source Repositories with service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, gcloud-cli, google-cloud-source-repos

Is it possible to access a [Google Cloud Source Repository](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/cloud-repositories-local-repository) in an automated way, i.e. from a GCE instance using a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication)?

The only authentication method I am seeing in the docs is to use the `gcloud auth login` command, which will authenticate my personal user to access the repo, not the machine I am running commands from.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to clone with `git` rather than running through `gcloud`, you can run:

```
git config --global credential.helper gcloud.sh
```

...and then this will work:

```
git clone https://source.developers.google.com/p/$PROJECT/r/$REPO
```

Answer (score 7):

On GCE vms running

```
gcloud source repos clone default ~/my_repo
```

should work automatically without extra step of authentication, as it will use VMs service account.

If you running on some other machine you can download from https://console.cloud.google.com service account .json key file and activate it with

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file KEY_FILE
```

and then run the above clone command.

Comment: For me it gives
fatal: remote error: 
Invalid authentication credentials.
Please generate a new identifier:
  https://source.developers.google.com/auth/start?scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

I tried giving VM service account permissions in https://console.cloud.google.com/code/develop/repo still same error.

Comment: I got it working, need to select "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs" when creating an instance. Otherwise VM service account doesn't have a scope needed, and even with IAM roles granted can't access the repo.

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody like me was trying to do this as part of Dockerfile, after struggling for a while I've only managed to get it to work like this:

```
RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file KEY_FILE ; \
    gcloud source repos clone default ~/my_repo
```

As you can see, having it to be part of the same RUN command was the key, otherwise it kept failing with

```
ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) You do not currently have an active account selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable access to the "Cloud Source Repositories" Cloud API for the instance. You should do this while creating or editing the instance in the [Admin console](https://admin.google.com)
2. From a shell inside the instance, execute `gcloud source repos clone <repo_name_in_cloud_source> <target_path_to_clone_into>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on GCE, take advantage of the new authentication method that needs fewer lines of code.

When creating your VM instance, under "Access & Security," set "Cloud Platform" to "Enabled."

Then the authentication code is this simple:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
```

See
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials